# Using ellipsis in function to read in data using tidy principles

Tags: r, tidyverse, ellipsis, rlang

I'm trying to write an upload data function for an R package and I'd like to be able to pass arguments via the ellipsis to a child function I'm using to read in the data. My function is below,

```
upload_data_excel <- function(directory_path, ...) {

  # capture ellipsis
  dots <- rlang::list2(...)

  # list of file names for upload
  file_list <- list.files(directory_path, pattern = '*.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

  # concatenate data files
  data <- file_list %>% purrr::map_dfr(~ readxl::read_excel(., !!! dots))

  # clean column names
  data %<>% janitor::clean_names(case = 'snake')

  # output concatenated tibble
  return(data)

}
```

Sometimes the ellipsis will be empty, so I want it to work in that case too. I keep getting an error

```
Error: `sheet` must have length 1
```

Is this approach correct? The error suggests that I'm not unpacking the dots correctly in the read_excel function. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use `tryCatch` or `possibly` orr `safely` to capture

Comment: Why not just do `if(length(dots) == 0) data <- file_list %>% purrr::map_dfr(~ readxl::read_excel(.)) else data <- file_list %>% purrr::map_dfr(~ readxl::read_excel(., !!! dots))`